# Criando uma tabela em html

Tags: html

Eu gostaria de saber se é possível construir uma tabela igual a esta em `html`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A tabela ainda não possui registro nenhum, são apenas dois cabeçalhos em que o primeiro ocupa mais do que uma coluna.

Comment: Dê uma olhada em: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp

Comment: Obrigado ajudou-me.

Answer (score 2):

- Construa primeiro a tabela em HTML (na mão mesmo).
- Depois utilize o .append() do Jquery para criar ela dinâmicamente.
- Por fim coloque os valores dinâmicos.

Poder utilizar um loop para as iterações dos valores.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o `colspan`. O colspan server para unir mais de um coluna.

[Um exemplo aqui.](http://pt-br.html.net/tutorials/html/lesson11.php)

Comment: Obrigado mas eu já consegui resolver o problema. Mas obrigado na mesma.

Answer (score 2):

Fiz assim:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
     <thead>
          <tr>
               <th colspan="2"><h4>Operário</h4></th>
               <th colspan="3"><h4>Intervenção</h4></th>
               <th colspan="3"><h4>Avaria</h4></th>
               <th colspan="5"><h4>Prevista</h4></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
               <th>Id</th>
               <th>Identidade</th>
               <th>Data</th>
               <th>Hora</th>
               <th>Duração</th>
               <th>Data</th>
               <th>Descrição</th>
               <th>Impedimento</th>
               <th>Contagem</th>
               <th>Duração</th>
               <th>Fazer</th>
               <th>Tempo</th>
               <th>Ficha</th>
          </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>

     </tbody>
</table>
```